# How to include associations in thinking sphinx rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Using `thinking-sphinx` to fetch records and it works fine. But the issue is that I want to fetch associated records also in results to improve site performance.

Like I want to fetch pictures of articles also along with articles .

Tried this one but its not working

```
 Article.search :include => [:pictures]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Try `includes` instead of `include`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Thinking Sphinx v3](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v3/searching.html#advanced), the `:include` option is now within the `:sql` option:

```
Article.search :sql => {:include => :pictures}
```